# Javascript Add Div on the fly which ul list link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace having to create a sub list and instead I want to add the div's via javascript / jquery.

Here is what I have:

```
<script>
function makepage() {
var myvariable1="myTitle";
var newPage = $("<div>'+myvariable1+'</div");
//appendTo here?
</script>

...
```

Then the list:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" id="myid" onclick="makepage();">Click Here</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The reason code creating it dynamically is that I want to pass some variables to it internally and I don't want to use a form / post etc...

How can I make newPage appear when I click myid link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make sure you use the quotes you started with and append to body or what element do you want:

```
<script>
    function makepage() {
        var myvariable1="myTitle";
        var newPage = $("<div>"+myvariable1+"</div>");
        $("body").append(newPage);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a specific function and using in-line delegations, try the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="myid">Click Here</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('#myid').click(function() {
    var myvariable1 = "myTitle";
    var newPage = $("<div>"+myvariable1+"</div>");
    $('body').append(newPage);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WredK/1)